# Using boost.serialization with STL containers as template parameters

Tags: c++, stl, boost-serialization

I'd like to use boost.serialization with a templated container class:

```
// MyContainer.h

template<class T> struct MyContainer {
    T t;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& archive, const unsigned version) {
        archive & t;
    }
};
```

When I use an STL container as template parameter, e.g.

```
// Main.cpp
...
MyContainer<array<int,4>> mc;
std::ofstream ofs("foo.bar");
boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
oa << mc;
...
```

...Visual Studio 11 complains with the following error message:

```
'serialize' : is not a member of 'std::array<_Ty,_Size>'
```

I have tried to include "boost/serialization/array.hpp" in both files, but this didn't solve the problem. Besides, including the array specialization is not what I want, as the container may hold any other STL container as well.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [serialiation/array.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/serialization/array.hpp) has a `serialize()` overload for `boost::array`, it doesn't have one for `std::array`.

You should be able to provide your own `serialize()` overload using [`make_array()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html#arrays) instead:

```
namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template<class Archive, class T, size_t N>
void serialize(Archive & ar, std::array<T,N> & a, const unsigned int version)
{
  ar & boost::serialization::make_array(a.data(), a.size());
}

} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the compilation error. Still, if the template parameter was e.g. a map, yet another specialization would be required. Is there a generic way of doing this?

Comment: @untraceable: `map`, `set`, `vector`, etc. are already supported - include `serialization/map.hpp`, etc.

Comment: So basically, if I want to use MyContainer with a different type, I have to go back to MyContainer.h and include the appropriate boost.serialization header?! In my opinion this kind of defeats the purpose of generic programming :-)

Comment: @untraceable: It's enough to include it in the user code, i.e. the specific serialize overloads need to be visible where your container actually gets serialized with the type in question.

Comment: Seems obvious enough now. I forgot that C includes work by copy/paste :-)